# Angular 5.0 StaticInjectorError

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material-5

I trying to open Dialog. When I press a button but I have this error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UsertableComponent -> MatDialog]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UsertableComponent -> MatDialog]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
        at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
        at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
        at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
        at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
        at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10837)
        at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12070)
        at resolveDep (core.js:12560)
```

The file userbtable.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'usertable',
  templateUrl: './usertable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usertable.component.scss']
})
export class UsertableComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'firstname', 'middlaname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'company', 'position', 'actions'];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(private UserService: UserService , public dialog: MatDialog) { }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    //debugger;
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  openDialogEditUser(profilUser: string) {
    console.log('EDIT');
  }
  openDialogDeleteUser(profilUser: string) {
    console.log('DELETE');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.UserService);
    console.log(this.UserService.getUser());
  }

  //@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  constructor(private UserService: UserService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.UserService.getUser();
  }
  disconnect() { }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-add-user',
  templateUrl: './dialog-add-user.component.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog() {
    debugger;
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAddUser, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: "this.name", animal: "this.animal" }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }

}
export class DialogAddUser {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAddUser>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: the app.module.ts

Comment: show your module. it seems you miss the module import

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsertableComponent,DialogAddUser } from './components/usertable/usertable.component';
import { MatTableModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Comment: import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatIconModule} from "@angular/material";
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

Comment: declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsertableComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

Comment: please update your initial post

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting an MatDialog  in UsertableComponent. Check whether have you registered it properly in providers List of your parent module(for ex App.module.ts) or at parent component (like AppComponent.ts) under which you want to create the instance of it.